# AR(1) process can be estimated using linear regression

Tags: regression, time-series, estimation, least-squares, autoregressive

Can the $AR(1)$ process represented as
$$ x_t= ax_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$
 be estimated by regressing $x_t$ on its lagged value $x_{t-1}$.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty standard. You can find this in most texbooks on AR models.

Comment: you can try it but you may get an estimate of $a$ whose absolute value is greater than 1.0. This invalidates the model the model as an AR(1) because it's not stationary. if you get an estimate for $a$ whose absolute value is less than 1.0, then you're okay.

Comment: You should constrain your OLS linear regression to have a zero intercept. How to do this is software-package specific. @mlofton is right about stationarity. But this will work even in the explosive case with $|a|\ge 1$.

Comment: @Peter Leopold: That constraint is okay but it won't solve the issue that $|a|$ can come back greater than 1.0.